# Update a DIV with 2 forms SQL query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

i have 2 forms in a html page.
I want to update a single  with results of both of forms. (form1 or form2 display results in the same .
DIV will be updated with 1 line coming from a .php file.

Here is my code :

My html page (2 forms) :

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="result.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="data1">
<input type="text" name="data2">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<form name="form2" id="form2" action="result2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="data3">
<input type="text" name="data4">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<div id="resultDIV"></div>
```

Script used :

```
$('#form1').submit(function () {
    $.post('result.php', $('#form1').serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
         $('#resultDIV').append(data);
    });
    return false;
});
$('#form2').submit(function () {
    $.post('result2.php', $('#form2').serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
         $('#resultDIV').append(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

But it doesn't work. This code opens result.php or result2.php in a new window.
(Edited)

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I though you should <form id="form1" .. 
also remember </form> ?

Comment: Also, you have not included ids in your forms but only name attributes. Either include `id = "form1"` in the first form and `id = "form2"` in the second or change the jquery submit line to `$('form[name=form1]').submit()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault();`

```
$('#form1').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('result.php', $('#form1').serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
         $('#resultDIV').append(data);
    });
    return false;
});
$('#form2').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('result2.php', $('#form2').serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
         $('#resultDIV').append(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I agree. `event.preventDefault()`  prevents the default behaviour of the browsers (reloading the page)

Comment: Yes, In this case going to the `action`

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. You are referencing the forms by their id, but they don't have one. You have to set their `id` attribute to `form1` and `form2`
2. You didn't close the `<form>` tag with `</form>`
3. You can use `.preventDefault()` to keep the page from redirecting

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="result.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="data1">
    <input type="text" name="data2">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2" action="result.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="data3">
    <input type="text" name="data4">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<div id="resultDIV"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#form1').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('result.php', $('#form1').serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
         $('#resultDIV').append(data);
    });

});
$('#form2').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('result2.php', $('#form2').serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
         $('#resultDIV').append(data);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answers. IDs was forgotten during editing this question, /form too. And with your modification, i got same problems. Page result.php is loading instead of updating my DIV (in source html page)

Comment: My code is same, only names are differents. In my form, action have to be  declare ? (because it's always declared in script....)

Answer (score 0):

This is my code now... Always result.php which is opened in a new window instead of updating my DIV

Script between head and /head

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$('#form1').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('result.php', $('#form1').serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
         $('#resultDIV').append(data);
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

and my HTML one ( something.html):

```
<form name="form1" action="result.php" method="post" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="data1">
<input type="text" name="data2">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<div id="resultDIV"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved with this code (if it can help others)

```
<script>
$(document).ready (function() {
$("form").submit(function () {
$.post("result.php",$(this).serialize(),function(texte){    
$("div#resultDIV").append(texte);  
});
return false;
}); 
}); 
</script>
```